# I want to pass date from vf page input date to soql Query

Tags: visualforce

I have written vf page with input date filed. When I change input date the value needs to pass in query and compare with createddate then I want to display matching records in page.

I have done almost but when I am using Createddate >: dat then only records are displaying. When I used Createddate =:dat  for that exact date it is not. I found reason for this.because Createddate is the date+time but we are passing date only. As a end user can not pass exact time with date. I want to display records based on user selected date automatically.

Code:

## Page

```
<apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            Date: <apex:input type="date" value="{!dat}" onChange="pickDate()"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Criteria">
```

### Controller

```
public class DisplayInputDateRecordsCtrl{

 public Date dat{get;set;}
 public List<Invoice__c> Invoices {get; set;}

 public PageReference executeSearch()
 {

  Invoices =[select id, createddate,Name, Invoice_Total__c,expirydate__c,(SELECT id, name, Quantity__c, Unit_Price__c FROM Line_Items__r)
            from Invoice__c 
            where createddate >: dat limit 20]; 
            //createddate =: dat   --->not displaing records

      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Two quick thoughts - you could add a formula field on Invoice__c that is DATEVALUE(Createddate) or have the comparison on createddate converted to date format using createddate.date().

Comment: how can i convert to date format..?

Comment: Please share example i was confused

Comment: Just want to test the date() method to see if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DAY_ONLY` (not an obvious name for a function that pulls the Date part from a Datetime) from the [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) in the where clause:

```
where DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(CreatedDate)) > :dat
```

combined with `convertTimezone` that deals with [Converting Time Zones in Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm).

See my colleague's blog post on this subject [Gotcha: convertTimezone() must be used in SOQL Date functions dealing with Datetime](https://force746.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/gotcha-converttimezone-must-be-used-in-soql-date-functions-dealing-with-datetime/) for more detail.

Comment: Good to see that I was on the right path at least.

Comment: Great.....your code is working perfectly...Thanks so much

Comment: could you please look on this

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140747/i-want-to-render-status-message-when-a-opportunity-stage-is-closed-lost-using-st/140748?noredirect=1#comment203152_140748